# Need window resize event to calculate height

Tags: javascript, angular, kendo-ui

I have a question regarding the grid height for scrollable grid. The thing is from [source](https://www.telerik.com/forums/grid-dynamic-height-for-scrolling)

This solution doesn't provide a good answer for me. Because it has

```
    styles: [`
  html, body, my-app {
    height: 100%;
  }
']
```

But my grid has many controls, I don't know have many rows in the grid. So I give a fixed height. Now I want to use dynamic height for the grid.

[demo stackblize](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pxiu4r)

Comment: your demo stackblitz link is broken

Comment: Fixed the broken link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment out the `[style.height.%]="100"` on the `<kendo-grid>` element; or if you need that one, add the following css: `.k-widget.k-grid { height:auto; }`

Update the **app.component.ts** from your [example stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pxiu4r) to the following:

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { products } from './products';
import { sampleProducts } from './products';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <kendo-grid [data]="gridData" >
            <kendo-grid-column field="ProductID" title="ID" width="40">
            </kendo-grid-column>
            <kendo-grid-column field="ProductName" title="Name" width="250">
            </kendo-grid-column>
            <kendo-grid-column field="Category.CategoryName" title="Category">
            </kendo-grid-column>
            <kendo-grid-column field="UnitPrice" title="Price" width="80">
            </kendo-grid-column>
            <kendo-grid-column field="UnitsInStock" title="In stock" width="80">
            </kendo-grid-column>
            <kendo-grid-column field="Discontinued" title="Discontinued" width="120">
                <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
                    <input type="checkbox" [checked]="dataItem.Discontinued" disabled/>
                </ng-template>
            </kendo-grid-column>
        </kendo-grid>
    `,
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
    styles: [`
  /*html, body, my-app {
    height: 100%;
  }*/
  /* Add the following if you don't remove [style.height.%]="100" from  <kendo-grid [data]="gridData" > */
  /*
  .k-widget.k-grid { height:auto; }
  */
    `]
})
export class AppComponent {
    public gridData: any[] = sampleProducts;
}
```